# Why don't I see race conditions when my processes are writing to file?

Tags: perl, cpan

I use the [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) module for fetching some pages. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

open FILE,">myfile" or die "cann't open file$!";
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

foreach $data (@all_data) {

    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    #doing the fetching here and get the result on parsed_string

    print FILE $parsed_string;
    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
```

Could someone expain why the results are OK and don't overlap one with the other even there is more than one process writing to the same File ?

Comment: Please format your code as code by putting 4 spaces at the front of each line.

Comment: In this code sample, you are opening a filehandle in read (`<`) mode and then `print`'ing to it. Is that what you meant to say?

Comment: I mean opening the file for write  on the parent proccess(i don't able to edit my question any more) and print to the file on the child processes

Comment: Because&nbsp;you are&nbsp;lucky.

Comment: If you want to be sure of no overlap, open the file in the child process and use flock().

Comment: Hi runig could you provide an example ?thanks

Comment: @Rubin: examples in perldoc: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html (or 'perldoc -f flock')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it something to race. Printing a single line doesn't create a resource contention. Does the output from this program do more of what you expect?

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

open FILE, '>', 'myfile' or die "cann't open file$!";
select FILE; $|++;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);

foreach $data ( 0 .. 100 ) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    #doing the fetching here and get the result on parsed_string

    print FILE "1. ";
    sleep 1;
    print FILE "Printing from ";
    sleep int( rand 3 );
    print FILE "$$\n";
    sleep int( rand 5 );
    print FILE "2. Print";
    sleep int( rand 2 );
    print FILE "ing from $$\n";
    $pm->finish;
}
```

I got:

```
1. 1. 1. 1. 1. Printing from 7515
Printing from Printing from 7517
Printing from Printing from 7519
2. Print7518
2. Print7516
ing from 7517
1. ing from 7515
2. Printing from 7519
1. Printing from 1. Printing from 7520
2. PrintPrinting from 7522
2. Print2. Print7521
ing from 7520
1. ing from 7516
ing from 7518
1. 2. Print1. 2. Printing from 7522
1. Printing from Printing from ing from 7521
Printing from 1. Printing from 7527
7524
2. Print7525
2. Printing from 7525
7526
1. Printing from ing from 7524
1. 2. Print from
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are lucky.

Comment: To those of you who keep flagging this answer: it is correct, if a bit terse.  Suggest downvoting if you don't like the way it was presented; two mods have looked at the answer already and deemed it acceptable.